# Setting output file name for the ROS video recorder

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the video recorder to save a video stream to a file using ros, but  I am having trouble setting the filename parameter.

This is the command I am using

> rosrun image_view video_recorder filename:="test" image:=/camera/color/image_raw

These are the messages in the terminal

```
[ INFO] [1548243269.519044136]: Waiting for topic /camera/color/image_raw...
[ INFO] [1548243269.722238288]: Starting to record MJPG video at [640 x 480]@15fps. Press Ctrl+C to stop recording.
[ INFO] [1548243271.470604124]: Recording frame 52
 Video saved as output.avi
```

The video is saved successfully, but it names the file "output" instead of "test" like I specified.

How do I set the filename parameter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313508/setting-output-file-name-for-the-ros-video-recorder/) by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try

> rosrun image_view video_recorder
> _filename:="/home/(usr name)/test.avi"  image:=/camera/color/image_raw

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2019-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0